# Displaying video capture in a picturebox

Tags: c#-3.0, picturebox, directshow.net

I have compiled the sample [PLayCap](http://sourceforge.net/projects/directshownet/files/) from the [directshow.NET](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/) website in C#.

PLayCap - This application creates a preview window for the first video capture device.

Although the program works fine, i need to add buttons to the form. I cannot do that since, the video capture is displayed on the entire form. I want it to be displayed on a picturebox, for instance picturebox1. So that I can move the picturebox1 a little up and put some buttons.

Does anyone know how to do that ?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to set handler of video render filter to picterbox handler.
use picturebox1.handler property

Comment: Can you please provide the code? 
I used the generated code from GraphEditPlus. It is showing on some video renderer. But I need to show the preview in the form picturebox.
I am using C#.